# Using DOMSubtreeModified mutation event. in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, mutation-events

I have used the following jQuery code on my page and everything works fine on chrome.But when I open up the respective page in firefox I get the Unresponsive Script Error.

I know as per DOM3 specification the mutation events have been deprecated. But Still if anyone could help me out here, I'll be obliged.

```
jQuery('#term').on("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
$("#term > .click-slide").click(function(){
            $(this).siblings().slideToggle();

            });
 });
```

Respective HTML is:

```
<div class="btn-slide" id="term">
    <div class="click-slide">
      <button>Search Terms </button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-box">
       <label><span>Novena</span></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like in Firefox, the call to `.slideToggle()` is triggering the `DOMSubtreeModified` event, while this is not happening in Chrome.  So basically in Firefox, something initially triggers the event which binds your click handler. All is good at this point. When you then proceed to click, the `slideToggle` happens as expected. However, that fires off the DOMSubtreeModified event and you then end up with two click event handlers both doing `slideToggle` because they were now registered twice. The next time you click is when the infinite loop happens.  Basically the multiple click events keep triggering `DOMSubtreeModified` which registers more click handlers which makes more `slideToggles` happen which triggers more `DOMSubtreeModified`s, and so on and so forth.  To fix this, you can use jQuery's `.one` which tells your page to only fire off that `DOMSubtreeModified` handler once, which prevents this loop. If that is not a suitable solution, you'll just need to come up with some other way to make sure the `.click` handlers do not get bound more than once.

```
jQuery('#term').one("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){   //Notice this is using .one and not .on
```

Check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m7anH/) - it is using `.one` but I was able to verify that when using .on, the problem happened in Firefox and not Chrome.

Comment: That's really well explained. I noticed what's happening when using ".on" in place of ".one" in the fiddle. Thanks.

Comment: wow... you answered my question and a question I had a while ago. I had never heard of the `.one` function

Answer (score 19):

Well this might not be a suitable answer here since the question was about **Mutation-events**, and the one posted below is using ***[MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)*** but still I'm posting it as some may find this useful.

This is the alternative I used for **DOMSubtreeModified event in case some nodes are being added in the DOM**.

```
var target = $( "#term" )[0];
// Create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function( mutations ) {
   mutations.forEach(function( mutation ) {
       var newNodes = mutation.addedNodes; // DOM NodeList
       if( newNodes !== null ) { // If there are new nodes added

        //alert('something has been changed');

      }
   });    
});

// Configuration of the observer:
var config = { 
    attributes: true, 
    childList: true, 
    characterData: true 
};

// Pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);
// Later, you can stop observing
// observer.disconnect();
```

Comment: nice concise mutation observer example. with some jquery. thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much for this.

Comment: Yes very helpful thank you! I modified to `mutations[0].addedNodes` to only get the 1st  mutation in my case. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Oh thank you so much !

I added the management of deleted nodes.

On the other hand, if a node is created or not, it is necessary to check if the array is empty

```
        var observer = new MutationObserver(function( mutations ) {
            mutations.forEach(function( mutation ) {
                var newNodes = mutation.addedNodes; // DOM NodeList
                var removeNodes = mutation.removedNodes;
                // console.log(newNodes)
                // console.log(removeNodes)
                if(newNodes.length !== 0) { // If there are new nodes added
                    console.log('create')
                }
                if(removeNodes.length !== 0) { // If there are old nodes
                    console.log('remove')
                    console.log(removeNodes[0])
                }
            });
        });
```