# moving an object created by JQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, element, appendto

I'm sure this has come up before, but I can't seem to search the right wording to find anything related.

I have an object i created with JQuery. (will actually a 3rd party plugin created it)

Since is was created after the dom was formed, it's not found as an object by JQuery.

I want to appendTo() this created object.

Isn't there a JQuery command that says "check if new elements have been added to the dom?

Comment: Can you show an example of what you want to do in a http://jsfiddle.net? As little code as possible to reproduce your problem would greatly improve our ability to help you

Answer (score 0):

That's called event *delegation*.  You can do this within the **[`on`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fon%2F&ei=oqcWVfnBE5PfgwTppoOADg&usg=AFQjCNGHxEOiEG7qWkC1vyf04wRn2n_rdA&sig2=dSjAFSMQTfY9mKOH3-011A&bvm=bv.89381419,d.eXY)** method:

```
$('table').on('click', 'td', function() {
  $( this ).addClass('highlight');
});
```

This adds the `highlight` class to all `td` elements, even those created after the event declaration.

However, in your particular example, `appendTo()` should be able to find newly-created elements, so I can't think of why event delegation is needed in that context.

Answer (score 0):

There is the JS [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) method which can detect DOM tree update. You can check if update correspond to your added object. 
An other helpful question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082158/using-domsubtreemodified-mutation-event-in-jquery).